# Excessive CPU usage while running Facebook and few other websites

Tags: cpu

I am running Linux Mint 17 (Linux Kernel 3.13.0-71-generic) on my HP Envy 17j (Core i7, Quad core). The laptop runs normal while using any programs. But when I open facebook.com or similar sites (e.g. Ziptask.com), then it starts consuming excessive CPU and the laptop overheats. The CPU usage is around 140%.

I tried with both Google Chrome and Firefox and it is the same case. Maybe it is trying to load some components like HTML5 graphics that are causing the problem.

What may be the correct way to diagnose and solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Install NoScript add-on to Firefox, and enable/disable scripts from different sites selectively.

(Your problem has to do with greedy scripts.)

Comment: also install AdBlock Plus or similar ad-blocker - it will block most (almost all?) of the javascript spyware that wastes your CPU spying on you as you browse the web.

Comment: Tried with both Adblock Plus, NoScript and on Incognito mode. I get the same problem.

Comment: Use Ublock Origin, it's much better than Adblock. But greedy and incompetently written and abusive javascript is the cause. Note that facebook itself isn't that bad, but ads are. Note that particularly adblock I believe made some very questionable deals with ad vendors about who to block. Also note, if you use noscript then allow all on a site, that defeats the purpose of using it, allow selectively.